# Error unpausing domain: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'cont': when starting to run VM that is ppc64el

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, ppc64le

**Explanation:**

I work for IBM and trying to prototype netboot (pxe) for ubuntu. The goal is to have a maas deployment server deploy out to 4 VMs managed under ubuntu 14.0.4 to test out juju bundle #39 (openstack base). Since my team does not have 4 physical servers we are attempting this using VMs. Note this is ppc64el environment.  Note that in current environment I did create a x86 PXE and had it commissioned from maa.  So we know ubuntu can build x86 PXE, bridge to maas and mass find the node and commission it.    IBM is trying to do this for the
ppc64 image now.  Once that works intend to move to ppc64le image (our goal).

**Related Ask Question:**

["Guest has not initialized the display yet". when starting to run VM that is ppc64el](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675013/guest-has-not-initialized-the-display-yet-when-starting-to-run-vm-that-is-ppc)

**Problem:**

Based on related Ask Question above changed VM to use console instead of graphics.  The graphics were removed.  Doing this caused VM to go to pause state and issue: Error unpausing domain: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'cont': Resetting the Virtual Machine is required

I do see VM console show blank with using ^] escape to close.  But that I figure is OK.  Also tried to do force reset and then a resume but that did not seem to do much.  Maybe missing fix to configuration xml below or my command sequence incorrect or maybe bug.

**StackTrace**

error unpausing domain: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'cont': Resetting the Virtual Machine is required

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 91, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 127, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1382, in resume
    self._backend.resume()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1919, in resume
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainResume() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'cont': Resetting the Virtual Machine is required

**Environment data**

root@ubuntur2n2:/virtualMachines/vm7# uname -a
**Linux ubuntur2n2 3.19.0-25-generic** #26-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:18:29 UTC 2015 ppc64le ppc64le ppc64le GNU/Linux

root@ubuntur2n2:/virtualMachines/vm7# lsb_release -d
Description:    **Ubuntu 15.04**

**VM details:**

Using VMM created new VM, select architecture ppc64, select Netowrk boot (PXE) image and continue thru panels to create VM. VM created OK but goes to pause when Run selected.

Hypervisor: kvm

Acrhitecure ppc64

Emulator   /usr/bin/qemu-system-ppc64

Firmware   default

Machine type pseries-2-2

**Configuration xml**

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>DaveBubuntutrustyppc64</name>
  <uuid>bd2e489e-b0ad-452b-a20a-69dd9241319f</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='ppc64' machine='pseries-2.2'>hvm</type>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-ppc64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/DaveBubuntutrustyppc64.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0'>
  <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0'>
      <address type='spapr-vio' reg='0x2000'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:3b:20:90'/>
      <source bridge='br3'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
      <address type='spapr-vio' reg='0x30000000'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <address type='spapr-vio' reg='0x30000000'/>
    </console>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='usb'/>
    <video>
      <model type='vga' vram='16384' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Comment: Used  ppc64_cpu --smt=off.  Also see: askunbuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/675013/guest-has-not-initialized-the-display-yet-when-starting-to-run-vm-that-is-ppc    More details were added under that askubuntu question on getting pcc64le VM working.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue on 16.04 on a power8 box, turning smt off lets me get it running but this should work with smt right?